# "Empty path not legal' in Uno Platform solution

Tags: c#, xaml, uno-platform

I am rebuilding my dev machine and am experimenting with Uno. I created new cross platform project and went to follow Uno Platform tutorial https://platform.uno/docs/articles/getting-started-tutorial-1.html .
I clicked on XAML file for main page and Visual Studio displayed an error.

'Empty path is not legal'

Anyone knows why this could be happening?

PG.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem found on Visual Studio and there is already an open issue to fix it.

You can follow the status here:  (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1267071/trying-to-open-xaml-files-shows-empty-path-name-is.html).

As a workaround you can open any `.cs` file from the Shared project then change the leftmost dropdown to target the `UWP` project.

This should allow you to open the the XAML file.

[image: Selecting the UWP Target]

Comment: If the dropdown keeps returning to previously selected option, restart the Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank  you - restarting Visual Studio helped resolve this